# How convert localString date to new Date?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have local string date: `12/3/2018, 12:00:00 AM`.

How to convert it to `Date()`?

Comment: Can you provide duplicated question?

Comment: I can just use `new Date("12/3/2018, 12:00:00 AM")` and it produces the wanted result, does this not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Z at the end of the localString

```js
var a=new Date('12/3/2018, 12:00:00Z');
console.log(a);
```